# Fixed height inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

This is my css

```
.f0{display: inline-block; padding: 5px;margin: 5px;height: auto;box-sizing: border-box}
```

and this is my html

```
<div>
<div class="f0" style="width:33%">1 line of data</div>
<div class="f0" style="width:33%">2lines of data<br/>I love foo</div>
<div class="f0" style="width:33%">3lines of data<br/>Love Bar too<br/>coffee too</div>
</div>
```

It will be rendered something like below (different height), I also expected to have all of them in one line, **but sometimes the 3rd. div goes to the next line**.

```
+--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+
|1 line of data|  |2lines of data|  |3lines of data|
+--------------+  |I love foo    |  |Love Bar too  |
                  +--------------+  |coffee too    |
                                    +--------------+
```

but I like table like output like this

```
+--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+
|1 line of data|  |2lines of data|  |3lines of data|
|              |  |I love foo    |  |Love Bar too  |
|              |  |              |  |coffee too    |
+--------------+  +--------------+  +--------------+
```

Now how may I fix this? `height:100%` doesn't work too.
**The main problem:**
I'm not insisting to fix the issue with this approach(but prefer), I also tried `display:table-cell` and its related stuffs and everything is working very well except ie6 and ie7, so the expected output is desired with any approach using divs(without any js).

Comment: Provide a fiddle demo to understand more your situation.

Comment: You are trying to support IE6 and IE7 without javascript? I am sure.. it is just not possible.

Comment: @Mr_Green fortunately I can make it happen with `table` for ie too, but I don't want to use `table` and use divs instead, no `js`. wonder why its everywhere!

Comment: it looks like you need to give fixed height

Comment: @user2889419 just use tables. why can't you use tables?

Comment: @Mr_Green because tables are not for layouting

Comment: @user2889419 Well, they are for layouting in IE6 and IE7..

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes cannot use `fixed-height`, dynamic data. not sure about the target fix sizes

Comment: @Mr_Green So you mean I specify a completely new page for my whole system because of two browsers? or fixing the html? and where is the logic here?

Comment: why support ie6? microsoft don't support ie6 anymore

Comment: @Pete yes sir, I know, but we had some requests with those(ie6,7) brothers

Comment: Hope you are charging them for it, they deserve some sort of punishment for not upgrading!  Thinking about it, does inline-block even work in ie6?

Comment: Pete, `inline-block` works from IE 5.5, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility). @user2889419 yes, you should compromise or go with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use `display:inline-table;`

```css
.f0 {
  display: inline-table;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="f0" style="width:33%">1 line of data</div>
  <div class="f0" style="width:33%">2lines of data<br/>I love foo</div>
  <div class="f0" style="width:33%">3lines of data<br/>Love Bar too<br/>coffee too</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After much thought and deliberation I think the only way you could possibly achieve what you are after without using JS is to add extra elements to your markup.

We can use additional elements to span the height of the tallest content but to do so would require us to use a fixed height on the parent and 100% for the children. We can avoid this by using a combination of `position: relative` on the parent and `position: absolute` on the `.background` elements. By specifying a `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` position, it would force the element to span the whole height.

However, these elements need to match the width of the div blocks so we share the width property between the cell and background classes.

This all works great apart from in IE6 and 7 which need to have an implicitly set left dimension to work, so we use a conditional comment and a set of redundent classes (.one, .two, .three) to set the left position for browsers less than or equal to IE7.

The end result is this (note the conditional comment is in with the HTML):

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px; /* you don't need this it's just for practicalities */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.f0,
.f0Background {
    width: 33.333%;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
}
.f0 {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.f0Background {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: #333;
}
```

```html
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>

.f0Background.one {
    left: 0;
}
.f0Background.two {
    left: 33.333%;
}
.f0Background.three {
    left: 66.666%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<div class="container">
    <span class="f0Background one"></span>
    <div class="f0">Cell 1.</div>
    <span class="f0Background two"></span>
    <div class="f0">Cell 2.</div>
    <span class="f0Background three"></span>
    <div class="f0">Cell 3 pushes the content all the way down using this text which serves no purpose other than to push the content down..</div>
</div>
```